# Sell digital products by physical cards outside the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I created an app for selling digital animated book and playing them by the app and app uses in-app purchase for selling books.

Now i want to sell PHYSICAL cards with some codes in them outside the app (obviously) and
when user enter the code in app they can use all books for some period of time.

is it against apple rules or not?

also i know can use in-app purchase instead of physical cards but my client want to sell physical cards in some area of the world, that most of people do not have credit cards and cant use in-app purchase.

Comment: can you implement functionality of sell Physical products?